# Remodelación de ventana GLFW

Tags: c++, opengl

Estoy trabajando con una ventana de la biblioteca **glfw3** en **VS C/C++**
Esta ventana es redimensionable, el problema es que "se rompe al manipularla",
He **resaltado el símbolo de cambio de tamaño** para mostrar que siempre que estire la pantalla en alguna dirección y mantenga presionado el botón izquierdo del mouse, la representación no se ajusta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es ¿qué método puedo usar para remodelar la representación mientras lo manejo? y asi evitar que se vea el fondo negro, En la biblioteca GL/glut.h existe el método glutReshapeFunc() para hacer precisamente esto, pero no estoy usando glut.h, estoy usando glfw.h, con la documentación oficial no he sabido encontrar una manera para hacerlo.

Código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void HideConsole()
{
    ::ShowWindow(::GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
}

void window_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

void processInput(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}

void processInput(GLFWwindow* window);

void render_menu_backround()
{
    // X Axis.           // Y Axis.
    GLfloat p0x = 0.5f;     GLfloat p0y = 0.5f;
    GLfloat p1x = 0.5f;     GLfloat p1y = -0.5f;
    GLfloat p2x = -0.5f;    GLfloat p2y = -0.5f;
    GLfloat p3x = -0.5f;    GLfloat p3y = 0.5f;

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2d(p0x, p0y);
    glVertex2d(p1x, p1y);
    glVertex2d(p2x, p2y);
    glVertex2d(p3x, p3y);
    glEnd();
}

int main(void)
{
    HideConsole();
    int width = 700;
    int height = 500;
    glfwInit();
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Cube", NULL, NULL); 
    glfwSetWindowSizeLimits(window, 900, 800, GLFW_DONT_CARE, 1000);
    glfwMaximizeWindow(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);


    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        processInput(window);
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.35f, 0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        render_menu_backround();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: La solución como tal va por OpenGL, indicándole que el área de dibujo cambió con [`glViewport`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glViewport.xhtml). También te sugiero que uses un loader como [glew](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) o [glad](https://glad.dav1d.de/) y que aprendas OpenGL moderno.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he resuelto, gracias a otra publicación de stackoverflow, básicamente lo que ocurría era que cuando ponía el cursor en el borde de la pantalla y le daba clic izquierdo para cambiar el tamaño de la ventana, mi programa se detenía y se reanudaba cuando soltaba el clic, para que mi programa siguiera corriendo tenia que generar otro hilo de proceso con la librería pthread.h, con ella es cuestio de crear una función

```
void* threadfun(void* arg);
```

y poner dentro las funciones de ventana

```
void* threadfun(void* arg) {
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwInit();
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.35f, 0);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        processInput(window);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        render_menu_backround();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        framebuffer_size_callback(window, width, height);
        glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

aplicarlo fuera del main y dejar el otro while solo para las funciones de cerrado y listo ventana responsiva.

codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void HideConsole()
{
    ::ShowWindow(::GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
}

void window_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

void processInput(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}

void processInput(GLFWwindow* window);

void render_menu_backround()
{
    // X Axis.           // Y Axis.
    GLfloat p0x = 0.5f;     GLfloat p0y = 0.5f;
    GLfloat p1x = 0.5f;     GLfloat p1y = -0.5f;
    GLfloat p2x = -0.5f;    GLfloat p2y = -0.5f;
    GLfloat p3x = -0.5f;    GLfloat p3y = 0.5f;

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2d(p0x, p0y);
    glVertex2d(p1x, p1y);
    glVertex2d(p2x, p2y);
    glVertex2d(p3x, p3y);
    glEnd();
}

GLFWwindow* window;
void* threadfun(void* arg);
  
int width = 700;
int height = 500;

int main(void)
{
    HideConsole();
    pthread_t mythread;
    glfwInit();
    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Cube", NULL, NULL);
    glfwSetWindowSizeLimits(window, 900, 800, GLFW_DONT_CARE, 1000);
    glfwMaximizeWindow(window);
    pthread_create(&mythread, NULL, &threadfun, (void*)NULL);

    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) 
 
        glfwWaitEvents();
        pthread_join(mythread, NULL);
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
        glfwTerminate();
   
    return 0;  
}

void* threadfun(void* arg) {
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwInit();
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.35f, 0);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        processInput(window);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        render_menu_backround();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        framebuffer_size_callback(window, width, height);
        glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
    }
    return 0;
}
```